# Error using python to import data in hive

Tags: python, hadoop

I am learning using python to import data into Hive on hadoop, here is the python code:

```
import sys
import datetime

for line in sys.stdin:
    line = line.strip()
    userid, movieid, rating, unixtime = line.split('\t')
    weekday = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(float(unixtime)).isoweekday()
    print '\t'.join([userid, movieid, rating, str(weekday)])
```

Here is the Mapper script:

```
CREATE TABLE u_data_new (
userid INT,
movieid INT,
rating INT,
weekday INT)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t';
add FILE weekday_mapper.py;
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE u_data_new
SELECT
TRANSFORM (userid, movieid, rating, unixtime)
USING 'python weekday_mapper.py'
AS (userid, movieid, rating, weekday)
FROM u_data;
```

Below is the error message I received:

```
Diagnostic Messages for this Task:
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Hive Runtime Error while processing row {"userid":222,"movieid":298,"rating":4,"unixtime":"877563253"}
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecMapper.map(ExecMapper.java:168)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:54)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:453)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:164)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Hive Runtime Error while processing row {"userid":222,"movieid":298,"rating":4,"unixtime":"877563253"}
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator.process(MapOperator.java:574)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecMapper.map(ExecMapper.java:159)
```

Prior to the above error message I have have the following output which seems to me that the map jobs are completed and succeeded:

```
2016-06-17 13:56:34,782 Stage-1 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
2016-06-17 13:56:46,501 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 0%
2016-06-17 13:56:47,871 Stage-1 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
2016-06-17 13:57:17,275 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 0%
```

My question is what is causing the error and how to fix it? What is the meaning of 100% for map?

Thank you very much.

P.S. Here is the data:

```
196     242     3       881250949
186     302     3       891717742
22      377     1       878887116
244     51      2       880606923
166     346     1       886397596
298     474     4       884182806
115     265     2       881171488
253     465     5       891628467
305     451     3       886324817
....
```

Comment: Your data is JSON, so `FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'` doesn't make much sense

Comment: I have no clue why it is like that, what's your suggestion to this? Thanks.

Comment: I can't follow what the data flow here is... Is the Python reading in JSON data from stdin? It doesn't look like it. Please [edit] your question to show the data.

Comment: sample data posted in OP, thank you.

Comment: Okay, that does look like tab delimited data, so where are you getting JSON? What's in `u_data`?

Comment: here are the description of the data:
u.data     -- The full u data set, 100000 ratings by 943 users on 1682 items.
              Each user has rated at least 20 movies.  Users and items are
              numbered consecutively from 1.  The data is randomly
              ordered. This is a tab separated list of 
          user id | item id | rating | timestamp. 
              The time stamps are unix seconds since 1/1/1970 UTC

Comment: u_data download: http://files.grouplens.org/datasets/movielens/ml-100k.zip

Comment: Hmm, that also says tab separated... I doubt the python is the problem, but it isn't required, actually. I believe you can convert time strings within Hive alone

Comment: can you show me the right steps you would take to finish this import? what would be the best practice? I just started hadoop learning. Thank you very much.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115004/discussion-between-mdivk-and-cricket-007).

Comment: You just want the weekday from that unix timestamp, yes?

Answer (score 0):

I just noticed this in the traceback:

**while processing row**`{"userid":222,"movieid":298,"rating":4,"unixtime":"877563253"}`

**"unixtime"** is a string and according to your table it should be `weekday INT`.

Comment: Thanks. 
In the py: weekday = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(float(unixtime)).isoweekday()
it is an int
Maybe the last line print '\t'.join([userid, movieid, rating, str(weekday)])? I will try to take away str

Comment: I modified the py so the last line is:
print '\t'.join([userid, movieid, rating, weekday])
I ran the import again and the error seems the same:

Comment: What about using `weekday = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(float(time.time())).isoweekday()` instead ?

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately the error message doesn't change